# Dataset's TBytes column and SQL VarBinary field combination

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2009

select convert(varbinary(8), 1)  in MS SQL Server produces output : 0x00000001

On assigning the above query to dataset in Delphi, and accessing field value, we get byte array as [1, 0, 0, 0] .  So Bytes[0] contains 1.

When I use IntToHex() on this bytes array it would result me value as "10000000" .

Why is IntToHex considering it in reverse order?

Thanks & Regards,

Pavan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to include a reference to the code where you're somehow calling `IntToHex` on a `TBytes` array. It's from the answer to your previous question, [how to convert byte array to its hex representation in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060321/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-its-hex-representation-in-delphi).

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060321/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-its-hex-representation-in-delphi/1060455#1060455), I forgot to account for how a pointer to an array of bytes would have the bytes in big-endian order while `IntToHex` (and everything else on x86) expects them in little-endian order. The solution is to switch them around. I used this function:

```
function Swap32(value: Integer): Integer;
asm
  bswap eax
end;
```

In the meantime, I fixed my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [little/big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem. Just reverse the byte array or the return value from IntToHex. Another way would be to do it yourself:

```
myInt = Bytes[0];
Inc(myInt, (Bytes[1] shl 8));
Inc(myInt, (Bytes[2] shl 16));
Inc(myInt, (Bytes[3] shl 24));
```

Also be careful with the sign. Is the SQL value signed or unsigned - the Delphi datatype should match this (int/longint is signed, Longword/Cardinal is unsigned - see [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=DataTypes) or in the Delphi Help).

Answer (score 0):

Because the x86 CPU uses little-endian numbers, a numbering system which orders its bytes in reverse order.  You'll need to swap the byte order to get the right value.