# Read GUID value stored in registry

Tags: windows, delphi, registry, delphi-7

I try to read a GUID value stored as a `binary` value in registry in Delphi.
When I read it with BintoHex, but the result is in reverse order.
It seems that I have to swap bytes but I thought BinToHex would do it.

I refered to this thread but I can't find the right solution :
[how to convert byte array to its hex representation in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060321/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-its-hex-representation-in-delphi/1060455#1060455)
It seems that it is due to little Eendian.

Below, you can see the GUID stored in registry

Here is my code :

```
var
s : string;
buffer : pointer;
...

begin
getmem(buffer, 1024*1024);
....
reg.ReadBinaryData(iValueOfregistry, buffer^, 1024*1024);
....
bintohex(pointer(longint(buffer)+14), PChar(s), 32);
```

Output for s :
**90E24D373F126545916439C4925E467B**

GUID should be FOLDERID_Downloads GUID :
**{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}**

Please help
[image: Here]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A GUID in binary form is best thought of as a record. Indeed in Delphi the record already exists – it is [`TGUID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TGUID).

All you need to do is to copy the relevant bytes directly into a variable of type `TGUID` and your job is done. If you want a string representation, use `GUIDToString`.

```
var
  GUID: TGUID;
  strGUID: string;
....
GUID := PGUID(PAnsiChar(buffer)+14)^;
strGUID := GUIDToString(GUID);
```

This will take care of all the endian issues automatically. Let's take a look at the declaration of `TGUID`:

```
TGUID = packed record
  D1: LongWord;
  D2: Word;
  D3: Word;
  D4: array[0..7] of Byte;
end;
```

Your code treats this as a straight array of bytes. However, in the record, `D1`, `D2` and `D3` are integral types on a little endian machine. So your code reverses the first 4 bytes, those belonging to `D1`. It then reverses the two bytes of `D2`, and also the two bytes of `D3`. The array of 8 bytes at the end of the GUID are not reversed, of course.

So, whilst you could readily do all the byte swapping yourself, it's far better to use a record to do so, and take advantage of the helper function that converts a binary GUID record to a properly formatted GUID string.

Comment: The GUID is not the only thing stored in the binary registry value. So, I have to read it in a buffer and read TGUID at position $e in that buffer. I suspect a "move" from buffer (at position $e) to GUID will not do the job because it is a byte-to-byte copy. Is that true? What do you suggest, David?

Comment: A `Move` will do the job perfectly. Just blit the data onto a `TGUID` and the job is done. It can be done without move using a cast to `PGUID`. The latest update shows you how.